# Kotlin SurfaceView / lateinit property surface has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception, surfaceview, lateinit

I’m still quite green and don’t know some of the features of the language. I face the following problem here is my code:

```
private lateinit var surface: SurfaceView
private var _binding: FragmentItem2Binding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
    _binding = FragmentItem2Binding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root

     }


override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    surface?.findViewById<SurfaceView>(R.id.surf)
        this.surface!!.holder!!.addCallback(object : SurfaceHolder.Callback {
            override fun surfaceCreated(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
               TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun surfaceChanged(
               holder: SurfaceHolder,
               format: Int,
               width: Int,
               height: Int,
            ) {
               TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun surfaceDestroyed(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
               TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
        })
```

xml:

```
\<SurfaceView
    android:layout_width="400sp"
    android:layout_height="400sp"
    android:id="@+id/surf"
\\\>
```

If I put:

```kotlin
lateinit var
```

it gives:

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property surface has not been initialized
```

If I put:

```kotlin
private var surface: SurfaceView? = null
```

it gives the error:
`java.lang.NullPointerException`

What should I do?

Comment: You are not setting `surfaceView` anywhere. I think you mean to call `binding.surf`?

Comment: I wanted to do : surface = findViewById<SurfaceView>(R.id.surf) , but I got:   Unresolved reference: findViewById.  I need to access the override functions, for the time being, 
I do not need binding.surf , if I understood the question correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not initializing the value anywhere.  Try:

```
surface = findViewById<SurfaceView>(R.id.surf)
```

or in viewBinding:

```
surface - viewBinding.surf //or what ever the id of the surface is
```

Comment: The problem is that when writing : surface = findViewById<SurfaceView>(R.id.surf)      I got :  Unresolved reference: findViewById

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to run it:
surface = view.findViewById(R.id.surf)
it was necessary to move the expression to override fun onViewCreated Where was the View.
Sorry for wasting your time, now my question seems pretty stupid)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).